# Textbook says to integrate a fraction using 'Taylor's formula'?

Tags: taylor-expansion, indefinite-integrals, substitution, partial-fractions, change-of-variable

I don't understand the solution my textbook gives for this problem:
$$ 
\int \! \frac{x^3}{(x+1)^5} \, \mathrm{d}x 
$$

I thought it had to be done with partial fractions, but I couldn't get it right, and when I checked the solution, it said "through Taylor's formula, you get:"
$$
\frac{x^3}{(x+1)^5} 
= \frac{-1 + 3(x+1) - 3(x+1)^2 + (x+1)^3}{(x+1)^5} 
$$

Is there a *Taylor's formula* I don't know about? Or is this an use of Taylor's expansion I cannot see? Also, is there a general rule for this decomposition?

[(I'm leaving here the textbook for reference, in case I mistranslated something)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q09Lu.jpg)

Thank you in advance. This is really driving me mad.

(I apologize for any mistakes, English is not my first language)

Comment: Here they are simply expanding the numerator  at $x=-1$.  You can do the same thing differently by letting $y=x+1$ and expanding the numerator.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand how exactly the numerator is expanded, though. (I'm sorry, I'm not good at this)

Comment: So, do it the way I suggested.  Let $y=x+1$, so the numerator is $(y-1)^3$ and expand that.  Otherwise, all they have done is to apply Taylor's expansion, $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {f^{(n)}(-1)}{n!} (x+1)^n$ to $f(x)=x^3$.